# Communicating between client and nodejs server errors in prod

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx, socket.io

I'm setting up a server in an AWS EC2 ubuntu instance that has a react frontend and a nodejs express server.  The two communicate via socket.io. Everything works fine locally but when hosted it logs `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and `GET ${url} net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. The server is running through pm2 and the client's index is called directly from nginx.

I've tried creating an endpoint in nginx for the server port and calling it through the url as well as trying to just use localhost, with similar results.

nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 443 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 default_server;
  root /var/www/[url]/client/build;
  index index.html;
  server_name [url] www.[url];
  location / {
    root /var/www/[url]/client/build;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[url]/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[url]/privkey.pem;
}
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 5000;
  server_name localhost; #also tried the url here (when also changed in the server)
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

Server:

```
//...
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const config = require('../client/src/config.json');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //...
    socket.on('send_url', (data) => {
        //connectUrl(data);
    });
});

io.listen(config.Global.serverPort);
```

example from client side:

```
import openSocket from 'socket.io';
const socket = openSocket(`http://localhost:${config.Global.serverPort}`);
//...
socket.emit('send_url', {
    url: this.state.sheetURL,
    googleId: this.props.user.googleId,
    eventId: this.props.curEvent
});
```

I am able to access the client successfully, but no communication happens between the client and the server. I've been working on this for a few days and googling around but can't get the many examples I've found to work.  This seems like a basic thing to do so I feel like I must be missing something obvious!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you open the 443 port on EC2 ?

Comment: Please enable 80, 8080, 443, 5000 port of ec2 in aws console.

Comment: Those ports are all already open

Comment: When you run this locally do you have nginx between the client and the server? I immediately think its the nginx config because websockets & proxies are notorious for not always working together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nginx configuration is creating a separate opening at port 5000, and then proxying it to a backend at port 5000 instead of diverting traffic to /socket.io to a different backend at port 5000. You need to put a socket.io location within the ssl server block.

```
server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl;
  listen [::]:443 default_server ssl;
  root /var/www/[url]/client/build;
  index index.html;
  server_name [url] www.[url];
  location /socket.io/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
  location / {
    root /var/www/[url]/client/build;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[url]/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[url]/privkey.pem;
}
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Side note #1: it also appears ssl on is deprecated in leu of doing `listen ... ssl`

Side note #2:

Do `http.listen` instead of `io.listen` since it appears express is also mounted by the http server. Underneath `io.listen` may just be calling `http.listen` so what you have may work, but it may be confusing what is actually going on.

Comment: Thanks! setting the socket.io stuff as a location block in the main server block worked perfectly. (also I think this helped me understand how nginx works a little bit better)